# How can I find a specific item in array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to find all completed items and assign them to a new array in React. Basically, I have to find the *count* of the completed items in array. How many completed items we have?

This is a way that I found but it does not work. Because I want to find completed item's length.

```
let object = tasks.find(o => o.completed === true);
```

This is my array:

```
      const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
    {
      id: 1, 
      text: "Go to Lake", 
      reminder: false,
      time: '08:00',
      completed: false
    },
    {
      id: 2, 
      text: "Push your works to github", 
      reminder: true,
      time: '13:00',
      completed: false
    },
    {
      id: 3, 
      text: "Buy groceries", 
      reminder: false,
      time: '15:00',
      completed: false
    },
  ]);
```

I tried to find a solution in Javascript documentation. Splice, find, filter methods. But I think I should try some other methods to solving this problem.

Comment: Try using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: You said you already used `filter`. What's not working with that?

Comment: filter function is the best option in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `filter` like:

```
let completedTasks = tasks.filter(task => task.completed)
```

And find the length like:

```
console.log(completedTasks.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const completedTasks = tasks.filter(task=>task.completed);
const count = completedTasks.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the *count* of matching elements, a simple loop does it:

```
let count = 0;
for (const {completed} of tasks) {
    if (completed) {
        ++count;
    }
}
```

or somewhat less obviously;

```
let count = 0;
for (const {completed} of tasks) {
    count += completed; // Since true => 1 and false => 0
}
```

There's no need to create an array as with `filter` just to throw it away once you have its length.

If for some reason you don't want to use a loop, you can use `reduce`, but it's complicated and easy to get wrong:

```
let count = tasks.reduce((count, {completed}) => completed ? count + 1 : count, 0);
```

Comment: That's a good old method, but why shouldn't we use the features that JS gives us? Like `filter` or `map`?

Comment: @poPaTheGuru - `map` doesn't make any sense here. `filter` creates an array. Creating an array just to get its length is IMHO not a great idea.

Comment: Yes, `map` is not the best solution, but you can do the job with it like for every completed task add it to another array and then take the length. What means `IMHO`? Newbie here

Comment: IMHO is internet slang for "in my humble opinion." Remember that `map` and `filter` **are** loops, they're just loops under the covers.

Comment: Yep, indeed, both are loops. It's just that somehow I am used to the features that are available and find it easier to write and read the code with `filter` than to create my own `for` method. Just another point of view :D

Comment: @poPaTheGuru - If you think readability is an issue, define a function that does it that has a reasonable name rather than doing it inline. :-)

Comment: Yeah, it's not just about the name itself, but also the steps. Maybe I think that way because I started to learn JS and React like a year - year and a half ago and somehow grew up with the features :D

Comment: @poPaTheGuru - It has nothing to do with "features." It just has to do with using the *right* feature. Creating an array just to through it away just because you don't like `for` loops? No, not in my view.

Answer (score 1):

There is no completed task in your array, maybe it's just a sample but otherwise your code should work. You can write it like this

```
tasks.find(o => o.completed);
```

The find method return object if found and nullish if not found.
Nulish : can be check with :

```
if(nulishObject) // not null or undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `reduce` method to loop through the array while counting the number of completed tasks at the same time.

```
const completedTasks = tasks.reduce((totalCount, task) => {
  if(task.completed) {
    return totalCount + 1;
  }
  return totalCount;
}, 0);
```

You can find [more information about reduce here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` to return a list of matches.

```js
tasks.filter(({ completed }) => completed
```

The `Array.prototype.find` function returns the first match only.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const fetchData = () => Promise.resolve([{
  id: 1,
  text: "Go to Lake",
  reminder: false,
  time: '08:00',
  completed: true
}, {
  id: 2,
  text: "Push your works to github",
  reminder: true,
  time: '13:00',
  completed: true
}, {
  id: 3,
  text: "Buy groceries",
  reminder: false,
  time: '15:00',
  completed: false
}]);

const CompletedTaskList = (props) => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then(setTasks);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Completed Tasks</h1>
      <ul>
        {tasks.filter(({ completed }) => completed)
          .map(({ time, text }) => (
            <li className="task">
              <span>{time}</span>
              <span>{text}</span>
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<CompletedTaskList />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
.task {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.125fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```